# Deleting multiple rows using IN sql statement in whereClause

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a list that performs multiple selections then delete the items that are selected using this method.

```
 public Integer deleteDesc(ArrayList<String> rows) {
    String[] args = rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()]);
    Log.i("AMS", "Args: " + args);
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("DropdownList", "Description IN (?)", args);
}
```

where the parameter ArrayList contains the items that were selected. I works when I only select one item but returns an error "bind or column index out of range".

I'm pretty sure it's the whereClause which cause it because I'm not sure how to correctly use the "?"

Comment: to use `IN` as a condition clause in sqlite/android number of `?` should match number of args, ex, if you have args [1,4,6] then the condition clause should be `"Description IN (?,?,?)"`

Comment: @Yazan Feel free to post an answer which handles an arbitrary number of parameters gracefully.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , i think it's not appropriate, as Elbert John Felipe did it but using `TextUtils.join()` and you did similar (dynamic args count) using native code, so i think my answer would be redundant, i thought it would be better if someone modify there answer, and make it closer to OP request, but **for sure** it's up to you, i can only suggest

Answer (score 0):

I used this statement `TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(args.length, "?"));`

working code:

```
 public Integer deleteDesc(ArrayList<String> rows) {
    String[] args = rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()]);
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("DropdownList", "Description IN (" + TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(args.length, "?"))
            + ")", args);
}
```

Comment: This does not use prepared statements and is therefore prone to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the `WHERE IN` clause using ? placeholders for each value using a prepared statement:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE Description IN (?");
for (int i=1; i < args.length; i++) {
    sql.append(",?");
}
sql.append(")");
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql.toString());
for (int i=0; i < args.length; ++i) {
    stmt.bindString(i+1, args[i]);
}
stmt.execute();
```

Note that using a prepared statement here is probably highly recommended, since you are deleting data.  Allowing a SQL injection in this method could have bad side effects.

Comment: actually, you still can use the `db.delete()` method, with the `where clause` param generated dynamically `..."Description IN (?,?,?)", args);` **Note: ? count = args.length**